# My laucher icon is glitching, its cut into half

Tags: android, icons

as title says, my ic_launcher cut into half, here is the pic

[image: my launcher icon]

this is the original:

[image: original icon]

how did this happen, is there any suggestion?

Comment: you using 9 patch image for the icon. use simple png image

Comment: You are using the wrong icon no need to use 9 patch image use normal png or jpg and import it  as icon set/asset

Comment: i'll try later tonight when I get to PC....thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using a png file.

or simple right click on your project, select new and then choose Image Asset. Now you will have plenty of options. 
It should work

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the following method.

```
Right click on drawable: new ->Image Asset
Select Launcher Icon in asset type
Select the path of the image you want to use as icon and keep the name as ic_launcher only.
next and finish.

You can customize it using the different checkboxes and options.
```

This should work for the launcher icons.

ps: not enough reputation to comment, so posting as a new answer. :/